# mongodb document contains $,the result is wrong

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I met a problem , when i insert document into mongodb with nodejs,the result is not

correct.Because the document contains the symbol of $,it conflict with mongodb's origin

operator $.

Can anybody help to solve this problem.Thank you!!!

Comment: You need to do a bit more work on this question: What is the code you ran? What is stored in the DB? How does this show up as a problem?

Comment: You are probably missing some quotation marks. Can you give more details?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://wiki.10gen.com/display/DOCS/Legal+Key+Names) for restrictions in key names in MongoDB documents:

"The '$' character must not be the first character in the key name."

Other locations of `$` character are fine, either in a key name or field value (if it's a string).